# xslt timezone conversion with daylight saving

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, timezone, dst

I am working with xslt and using the fn:current-dateTime( ) to get the current date time (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-current-dateTime). The time returned is in UTC. I need to convert this to PST. I see that the fn:adjust-dateTime-to-timezone (http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/fn_adjust-datetime-to-timezone.html) can be used to perform the timezone conversion. But i see that this function accepts the timeZone argument in the form of offset, i.e -PT8H for Pacific timezone while it is -PT5H for US Eastern Standard Time. When timezone is passed in terms of offset, its subject to modifications when Daylight Savings Time (DST) starts and ends right? Is there a better way for performing timezone conversion in xslt, a method that requires no modification periodically? or is there a recommendation when using fn:adjust-dateTime-to-timezone to handle this better?

Comment: Did you try a few date/times to see what it does?

Answer (score 4):

The XPath functions for manipulating timezone offsets work entirely in terms of numeric (duration) offsets, e.g UTC -5 hours or UTC +10 hours. They have no knowledge of civil timezone names or of daylight savings adjustments.

The one exception is the format-date[Time] function, where the fifth argument can be used to force conversion to the local timezone of a particular place, for example "America/New_York" - but it's somewhat implementation-defined whether such names are recognized. From the spec:

> If the $place argument is supplied in the form of an IANA timezone
>   name that is recognized by the implementation, then the date or time
>   being formatted is adjusted to the timezone offset applicable in that
>   timezone. For example, if the xs:dateTime value 2010-02-15T12:00:00Z
>   is formatted with the $place argument set to America/New_York, then
>   the output will be as if the value 2010-02-15T07:00:00-05:00 had been
>   supplied. This adjustment takes daylight savings time into account
>   where possible; if the date in question falls during daylight savings
>   time in New York, then it is adjusted to timezone offset -PT4H rather
>   than -PT5H. Adjustment using daylight savings time is only possible
>   where the value includes a date, and where the date is within the
>   range covered by the timezone database.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the information. I tried using the  format-dateTime function, but it looks like its converting the format of the dateTime value argument, i.e, if i use 'format-dateTime(fn:current-dateTime(), '[D] [MNn] [Y] [h]:[m01][PN,*-2]', 'en', 'OS', 'US-MA')"', where current-dateTime function returns value in UTC, this function returns the UTC time in the required format, so it only changes the format, not the timezone. If i pass the first argument as 'adjust-dateTime-to-timezone ', where i convert the utc time to required timezone, then it formats that time.

Comment: In continuation to the above comment, So however it looks like i need to use 'adjust-dateTime-to-timezone' for timezone conversion. is it true or am i missing something?

Comment: Is US-MA a recognized "place" with your chosen XSLT processor? The usual format for timezone names is continent/city, e.g. America/Boston.

Comment: I referred the xslt documentation for format-dateTime function, (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#date-time-examples), its mentioned that the value of the $country argument is from the ISO 3166 list, I got the value 'US-MA' from the ISO 3166-2 list. Is there a documentation page to get the timezone names in the format you have used? Also i tried using 'America/Boston', and i still see that the time is just formatted and not converted into Boston's eastern timezone.

Comment: What XSLT processor are you using? The details here are going to be processor-dependent. The tz database timezone names (also known as Olson timezones) are listed at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!  <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(current-dateTime(), '[FNn] [MNn] [D], [Y] [h]:[m01] [PN]', 'en', (), 'America/New_York')"/>

Answer (score 1):

Use this if the code is itself running in a US timezone:

```
<xsl:variable name="currentTimeZone" select="timezone-from-dateTime(current-dateTime())" />

<xsl:variable name="date_PDT_PST" select="adjust-dateTime-to-timezone($custom_date, xs:dayTimeDuration($currentTimeZone))" />
```