# Xslt conversion for dateTime in different timezone with day light saving

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, exslt

Looking for some help on xslt conversion for dateTime in different timezone with day light saving. How to handle EST vs EDT while doing dateTime conversion in xslt?

enter code here

```
Below is one Sample order xml which will be converted into another order format <salesOrders> using xslt. 
All dates in the "salesOrders" are supposed to be stored in GMT timezone. 

<!-- Input orders xml -->
<xml>
    <orders>
        <order>
            <order_id>1</order_id>
            <!--lots of other details -->
            <order_dateTime>2019/03/09 14:00</order_dateTime> <!-- yyyy/MM/dd hh24:mm-->
            <order_timezone>America/New_York</order_timezone>
            <!-- This time does not fall under day light saving ( UTC -0500) -->
        </order>
        <order>
            <order_id>2</order_id>
            <!--lots of other details -->
            <order_dateTime>2019/03/10 14:00</order_dateTime>
            <order_timezone>America/New_York</order_timezone>
            <!-- This time falls under day light saving timing ( UTC -0400) -->
        </order>
        <order>
            <order_id>3</order_id>
            <!--lots of other details -->
            <order_dateTime>2019/03/10 14:00</order_dateTime>
            <!-- format : yyyy/MM/dd hh24:mm-->
            <order_timezone>Asia/Kolkata</order_timezone>
            <!-- Indian Standard Time ( UTC +0530) -->
        </order>
    </orders>
</xml>

<!-- after xslt conversion, the date should be converted as given below.  -->

<xml>
    <salesOrders>
        <salesOrder>
            <salesOrderId>1</salesOrderId>
            <!-- required details -->
            <salesOrderDttm>2019-03-09T19:00:00</salesOrderDttm>    <!-- (14 + 5:00) -->
            <!-- converted the time into GMT (-04:30)-->
        </salesOrder>
        <salesOrder>
            <salesOrderId>2</salesOrderId>
            <!-- required details -->
            <salesOrderDttm>2019-03-09T18:00:00</salesOrderDttm>  <!-- (14 + 4:00) -->
            <!-- converted the time into GMT (-05:30)-->    
        </salesOrder>
        <salesOrder>
            <salesOrderId>2</salesOrderId>
            <salesOrderDttm>2019-03-09T08:30:00</salesOrderDttm>  <!-- (14 - 5:30) -->
        </salesOrder>
    </salesOrders>
</xml>

Need help for pupulating content of "salesOrderDttm"
    The content of <orderDateTime> and <orderTimeZone> will be used to populate <salesOrderDttm>.
    As mentioned above, it will be maintained in GMT (offset +0000) timezone.
    The main problem is, same Time zone being treated differently. At one time(first order), offset is +5:00 and at another time(2nd order) the offset is +04:30 

    How to do it in xslt?
    Came across adjust-dateTime-to-timezone() function, but that also expects us to provide the offset. 
    Is there any way to handle it?
    I hope this is a very common problem and must be solved
```

Saw this post, but all it says it is not possible what I am looking for. 
[Similar query on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47344723/xslt-timezone-conversion-with-daylight-saving)

Comment: Not sure what your question is. Please provide an example that clarifies what is your input and the expected output.

Comment: My bad, I was still editing the question to put more details. Thanks for asking!  Appreciate any help!

Comment: Th answer you have found is correct. You need to access the Olson database in order to know what that offset was in New York on the given date. XSLT does not have this capability.

Answer (score 4):

In XSLT 3.0 you can achieve this using the `$place` argument of the `format-dateTime()` function. Quoting from the Functions and Operators spec §9.8.4

> If the $place argument is supplied in the form of an IANA timezone
>   name that is recognized by the implementation, then the date or time
>   being formatted is adjusted to the timezone offset applicable in that
>   timezone. For example, if the xs:dateTime value 2010-02-15T12:00:00Z
>   is formatted with the $place argument set to America/New_York, then
>   the output will be as if the value 2010-02-15T07:00:00-05:00 had been
>   supplied. This adjustment takes daylight savings time into account
>   where possible; if the date in question falls during daylight savings
>   time in New York, then it is adjusted to timezone offset -PT4H rather
>   than -PT5H. Adjustment using daylight savings time is only possible
>   where the value includes a date, and where the date is within the
>   range covered by the timezone database.

Note that the way this is phrased gives implementations the option to "not recognize" timezone names; but let's assume they do.

First of course you need to convert `2019/03/09 14:00` to the `xs:dateTime` value `2019-03-09T14:00:00Z`, which is a simple bit of string manipulation.

Now you can determine the timezone offset for `America/New_York` by doing `format-time(xs:dateTime('2019-03-09T00:00:00'), '[Z]', (), (), 'America/New_York')`, which will give you a value such as "-05:00" (as a string). You can convert this to a dayTimeDuration `-PT05H00M` using more simple string manipulation, and then use `adjustDateTimeToTimezone()` to apply this displacement to your original date/time value.

The XSLT 2.0 version of `format-dateTime()` does not have this capability defined.

Comment: Thanks Michael ! Let me try this and I let you know it works.

Comment: Very detailed answer.